# Object.bcrypt.compareSync error: string undefined. Is there a working solution?

Tags: javascript, forms, express, bcrypt

On my rendered nunjucks template, I formed it to accept a username and a password that the user will type in. Upon clicking the submit button, it should search through a data base in my javascript express file to see if what the user typed in is in the database.

However I keep getting an error message.

I've made sure there are no spelling errors or anything like that but I'm not sure how to fix this error.
This is my error message:

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, undefined
    at Object.bcrypt.compareSync

My express code that is doing the handling of the submit button.

```js
let usersdb = new DataStore({filename: __dirname + '/usersDB', autoload: true});
app.post('/user', express.urlencoded({extended:true}), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    // Find user
    let auser = usersdb.find(function (user) {
        return user.username === username
    });
    if (!auser) {// Not found
        res.render("loginError.njk");
        return;
    }
//**** Its like the error happens on this line below*****
    let verified = bcrypt.compareSync(password, auser.passHash);
    if (verified) {

        let oldInfo = req.session.user;
        req.session.regenerate(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            req.session.user = Object.assign(oldInfo, auser, {
                loggedin: true
            });
            res.render("welcome.njk", {user: auser});
        });
    } else {
        res.render("loginError.njk");
    }
});
```

My expected result is that when the user enters in his username and password on the rendered nunjucks page (and its a valid username and password (valid meaning it was found in the usersdb)) it will render the welcome page.

If it is not found however, it should render the logerror.njk page

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: What does it display when you console.log(req.body.password) and console.log(auser)?

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously from your `verified` variable. Check the data your passing to `bcrypt.compareSync`. Also check if you added `select: false` to the password property on your schema if you're using mongoose/mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `findOne()` instead of find because find will return array of object `[{auserObject}]` so your `auser.passHash` will be undefine , put find return just your object `{auserObject}` and here you can use `auser.passHash`